# Trouble validating md5 hashed password with randomly generated salt?

Tags: php, hash, md5, salt, password-hash

I realize this is not as secure as it could be, but I want to do it this way.

I have this code which generates the password from a user's entry (*$password*)...

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$new_password = md5($salt . $password);
$new_password = $salt . $new_password;
```

This is how I'm trying to check against the saved password:

```
$split_salt = substr($saved_password, 0, 22);
$incomplete_password = md5($split_salt . $current_password);
$hashed_password = $split_salt . $incomplete_password;

if ($saved_password != $hashed_password) {

    $error = "error";

} else {

     //Validated

}
```

As far as I can tell this should work. However, I'm getting the error instead of the validation. Does this have something to do with MCRYPT not producing exactly 22 characters?

Comment: I hard coded both `$password` and `$current_password` to same values. And changed `$split_salt = substr($saved_password, 0, 22)` to `$split_salt = substr($new_password, 0, 22)` and it was validated. May be something wrong with your input of `$current _password` or `$saved_password' from database`??

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not what you want to hear, but your scheme is so utterly unsafe and a good solution is so simple to implement, that you should reconsider:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Your actual problem is the salt, `mcrypt_create_iv()` will return a binary string and it can very well contain \0 characters. So it is pure luck if your approach works or not.

Comment: The PHP on the client's server is very old. It doesn't support the password hashing functions. The data he is storing on here is not very important anyway

Comment: He would rather use this approach than get the company to upgrade the server. Don't ask me why. That's why I said specifi specifally that I know it isn't all that safe. What would be an alternative to IV? I've used that same process before, including substr (), with AES encryption and it worked fine.

Comment: @Allenph - Even if your site does not store sensitive data you can endanger users passwords, because they reuse the passwords on more important sites. There is a nice [cartoon](http://xkcd.com/792/) about this topic.

Comment: @Allenph - Since you can use the parameter `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`, you should also be able to use the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php). It works with PHP version 5.3.7 and later, but with a small change it even works with 5.3.